# How do I measure the duration of transient from a transient analysis graph?

Tags: capacitor, resistance, transient

I've assembled the following circuit:
[image: Figure 1]

And the following graph is the output: (Green: Voltage across C) (Red: Supply Voltage)
[image: Figure 2]

How do I measure the transient duration from the graph? Is it the same as the time period of oscillation?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Do you mean the green trace and its oscillation?

Comment: First, welcome to EE. By red trace you meant the supply voltage instead of voltage across the resistor, correct?

Comment: Oh yes red is the supply voltage. And yes the green trace and its oscillation.

Comment: It depends on the tolerance required by the application. Frequently, the \$\small 2\%\$ settling time, \$\small T_S\$, is used - the time taken to settle to within \$\small \pm 2 \%\$ of the final value.

Comment: So here it would close to 1.25ms, right?

Answer (score 1):

The duration of the transient response would be the time it takes the system to settle to a (new) equilibrium or a (new) steady state. By definition, this time is infinite.

A more common used term  is **settling time**. This is the time elapsed from the application of a change of input to the time at which the output has enters **and remains** within a specified error band, the time after which the following equality is satisfied:
$$V_3(t)-V_{3\text{, steady state}} \leq \epsilon$$

where 
\$V_{3\text{, steady state}}\$ is the steady-state value, and \$\epsilon\$ defines the width of the error band.

The answer depends on the error band as well on which time window is considered.
One can motivate the \$V_3\$ never settles, because its state changes every 1.25 ms.
When defining an error band to 4% of the steady state value and only consider 1.249 ms after voltage source V changed state, one can defined settling time of (about) 676 µs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How did you get the 676us settling time? Is it based on an approximation from looking at the graph?

Comment: @Aaron I simulated and measured it in LTspice